# How to get selected bundle items price

Tags: cart, bundled-product

I want to fetch price of selected Bundles Items on checkout_cart_product_add_after event. Is it possible to fetch ? How ?

For better idea of my query I am posting an image here.Please have a look.

[image]

Is there any way to change the price of sub bundle items on addtocart ?? In this case I want to change price of Camera,Case and Memory prices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find selected bundle items data at the time of add to cart, like below :

```
$options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
```

:)